# Flutter Stacked widget with Webview is not showing progressIndicator

Tags: flutter, dart

```
override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTab(),
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('View ' + type),
            ),
            body: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: WebviewScaffold(
                    url: weburl,
                    displayZoomControls: true,
                    withJavascript: true,
                    scrollBar: true,
                    withZoom: true,
                    hidden: true,
                  ),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: _isLoading,
                  child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ))
              ],
            )),
        onWillPop: backPress);
  }
Widget _bottomTab() {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.contact_page), label: "Dashboard"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.call), label: "Call"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.download_rounded), label: "Download"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.share), label: "Share"),
      ],
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    );
  }
 void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        break;

      case 1:
        _makingPhoneCall();
        break;

      case 2:
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
          getPermission('download');
        });
        break;

      case 3:
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
          getPermission('share');
        });
        break;
    }
  }
```

I have a webview with bottom navigation whenever i click bottom navigation i want to show progress indicator at the center of the webview.I tried stack widget with button and progressindicator its working but when i try to show the progress indicator with webview its not showing anything

Note:
Show progress indicator at center of webview when bottom navigation is clicked

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Visibility widget in Positioned widget Like this

```
Positioned.fill(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: Visibility(
                      visible: _isLoading,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )               
      ),
    ),
```

if this is not working then you can add initial child in WebviewScaffold like this

```
 WebviewScaffold(
                initialChild: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              
                url: weburl,
                displayZoomControls: true,
                withJavascript: true,
                scrollBar: true,
                withZoom: true,
                hidden: true,
              ),
```

Or you can also use

You can use the hide method to hide the webview whenever you want to display the progress.

Code:

```
final FlutterWebviewPlugin webviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin() ;
```

// when displaying the progress

```
webviewPlugin. hide() ;
```

Comment: tried your code but it doesn't working

Comment: let me check please

Comment: Check my Answer again let me know if the code is working

Comment: how can i trigger this initialchild every time when i click bottomnavigation

Comment: call setstate on bottomnavigation click

Comment: no i don't want to hide webview

Comment: https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/07/flutter-web-view-widget-progress-bar.html

Comment: this link did my trick

Comment: ok sure good luck

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code?

package: webview_flutter

```
bool isLoading = true;


Stack(
  children:[ 
    WebView(
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onPageStarted: (value){
        setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
        });
      },
      onPageFinished: (value){
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      },
      initialUrl: “Your URL”),
    isLoading == true? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()):Offstage()
    ])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).